# intellij is copying src to target

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I imported the following project into intellij idea: https://github.com/brendano/ark-tweet-nlp/

I managed to get a working jar built, but for some reason it's copying all the source files from /src/ into /target/, so the resulting jar also includes all the source files. How do I prevent this? If it helps I've included a screenshot of the directories below:

[image: screenshot of directories in intellij's left project menu]

Comment: Your pom.xml ist wrong.
I have checked out the project and there is no rule to build the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Settings window <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Click on the `Compiler` option.  You should see a list of `Resource Patterns` which determines which types of file IntelliJ will add to the target folder.
3. Add `!*.java;` to the list of resource patterns to *exclude* `.java` source files from being added to your `target` directory.

If this doesn't work, you can try adding a `<build>` tag to your Maven POM containing the following:

```
<build>
...
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/com</directory>
        <targetPath>com</targetPath>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
...
</build>
```

Comment: I put in the following: `?*.properties;?*.xml;?*.gif;?*.png;?*.jpeg;?*.jpg;?*.html;?*.dtd;?*.tld;?*.ftl;!*.java`, deleted the target dir and recompiled, but it's still moving the java files in.

Comment: Can you try putting in `!*.html` to see if it gets rid of the `package.html` file?  Just trying to debug your setup remotely, if possible.

Comment: I put in `?*.properties;?*.xml;?*.gif;?*.png;?*.jpeg;?*.jpg;!*.html;?*.dtd;?*.tld;?*.ftl;!*.java` and it doesn't get rid of `package.html` either, it's quite confusing.

Comment: Try modifying your POM file to exclude `*.java` files.

Comment: I changed `com` to `cmu` since src doesn't have any `com` dirs, but it's still including java files. Here's the entire pom file with my modifications prefixed by `+`: http://pastebin.com/HzW0V2TQ

Comment: I'm sure your code is fine.  Have you tried doing a Maven build from the command line?  This is obviously not a desirable long term solution, but it might get you through the day.  By the way, there may be a bug in IntelliJ 12 around this problem.